# Pandas - fill dataframe with date range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Assuming this is my df:

```
  Name1    Name2       date 
1 John     Jay   2015-01-01 06:01:00
2 Sara     Debra 2015-01-01 06:05:00
3 Ben      Beth  2015-01-01 06:09:00
```

I want to fill in the df where each row should be duplicated and incremented by 1 minute until it reaches to the next line, so the output should be:

```
  Name1    Name2       date 
1 John     Jay   2015-01-01 06:01:00
1 John     Jay   2015-01-01 06:02:00
1 John     Jay   2015-01-01 06:03:00
1 John     Jay   2015-01-01 06:04:00
2 Sara     Debra 2015-01-01 06:05:00
2 Sara     Debra 2015-01-01 06:06:00
3 Ben      Beth  2015-01-01 06:07:00
```

I looked into date_range, but I didn't find a proper way to do this without an ugly and inefficient for loop.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fill missing timestamps for Time column for a date in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187686/how-to-fill-missing-timestamps-for-time-column-for-a-date-in-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all datetimes are unique you can use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df1 = (df.set_index('date')
         .asfreq('Min', method='ffill')
         .reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
```

For me solution with [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) working with `DatetimeIndex` and [`Resampler.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('date').resample('1Min').ffill().reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df1)
  Name1  Name2                date
0  John    Jay 2015-01-01 06:01:00
1  John    Jay 2015-01-01 06:02:00
2  John    Jay 2015-01-01 06:03:00
3  John    Jay 2015-01-01 06:04:00
4  Sara  Debra 2015-01-01 06:05:00
5  Sara  Debra 2015-01-01 06:06:00
6  Sara  Debra 2015-01-01 06:07:00
7  Sara  Debra 2015-01-01 06:08:00
8   Ben   Beth 2015-01-01 06:09:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.resample('60S', on='date').pad()
```

It's a simple case of upsampling followed by `pad()` to fill forward the missing values.